# Overriding stem method in video classification model to change filter channel

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, resnet

I am trying to use torchvision’s video classification models [(R3D, R(2+1)D, MC18)](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torchvision/models/video/resnet.html#r3d_18) but my data is single channel (grey scale video), and these model uses 3 channel input, in that case I am trying to override the stem class , can someone please confirm if what I am doing is correct?

#### For R3D18 and MC18  `stem=BasicStem`

```
class BasicStemModified(nn.Sequential):


    def __init__(self):
        super(BasicStemModified, self).__init__(
            nn.Conv3d(1, 45, kernel_size=(7, 7, 1),  #changing filter to 1 channel input
                      stride=(2, 2, 1), padding=(3, 3, 0),
                      bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(45),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),

            nn.Conv3d(45, 64, kernel_size=(1, 1, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1, 1), padding=(0, 0, 1),
                      bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(64),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True))


model = torchvision.models.video.mc3_18(pretrained=False)

model.stem = BasicStemModified() #here assigning the modified stem


model.fc = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Dropout(0.3),
    nn.Linear(model.fc.in_features, num_classes)
)


model.to('cuda:0')
```

#### For R(2+1)D:

```
#For R(2+1)D model `stem=R2Plus1dStem`

class R2Plus1dStemModified(nn.Sequential):
    """R(2+1)D stem is different than the default one as it uses separated 3D convolution
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super(R2Plus1dStemModified, self).__init__(
            nn.Conv3d(3, 45, kernel_size=(1, 7, 7),   #changing filter to 1 channel input
                      stride=(1, 2, 2), padding=(0, 3, 3),
                      bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(45),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv3d(45, 64, kernel_size=(3, 1, 1),
                      stride=(1, 1, 1), padding=(1, 0, 0),
                      bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(64),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True))

model = torchvision.models.video.mc3_18(pretrained=False)

model.stem = R2Plus1dStemModified() #here assigning the modified stem

model.fc = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Dropout(0.3),
    nn.Linear(model.fc.in_features, num_classes)
)


model.to('cuda:0')
```

Comment: by making this change you prevent yourself from using the pretrained weights of these models - this is a shame.

Comment: I just need to train these model from scratch on my data, which is not acition recognition to begin with.

Comment: pre trained weights are very informative even if you train for different tasks. You should compare the performance and training time for pretrained vs "from scratch"

Comment: Modifying channels in my case for using pretrained weights is unfortunately the approach I cannot take, while I understand what  you are saying completely, the data I am using are stacked lossless medical images, keeping them as is remains the priority, the dataset is also normalized with different std deviation and mean than suggested for using with pretrained video classification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When switching from RGB to gray, the most simple way to go is to change the DATA and not the model:
If you have an input frame with only one channel (gray), you can simply [`expand`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.7.1/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.expand) the singleton channel dimension to span three channels. This is trivial and allows you to use  pre-trained models as-is.

---

If you insist on modifying the model - you can do so while preserving most of the pre-trained weights:

```py
model = torchvision.models.video.mc3_18(pretrained=True)  # get the pretrained
# modify only the first conv layer
origc = model.stem[0]  # the orig conv layer
# build a new layer only with one input channel
c1 = torch.nn.Conv3d(1, origc.out_channels, kernel_size=origc.kernel_size, stride=origc.stride, padding=origc.padding, bias=origc.bias)

# this is the nice part - init the new weights using the original ones
with torch.no_grad():
  c1.weight.data = origc.weight.data.sum(dim=1, keepdim=True)
```

Comment: Thankyou for this approach, since I am not using these model for action recognition, I   want like to train these model from scratch on my data, it's more experimental and I also don't want to copy the channels, but I appreciate this approach.